# Can we apply/delete kubernetes YAML files in IntelliJ IDEA/Visual Studio Code?

Tags: intellij-idea, kubernetes, visual-studio-code

Can we apply/delete kubernetes YAML files in IntelliJ IDEA/Visual Studio Code by right clicking on the YAML file and then choosing apply/delete/..?

Answer (score 2):

The [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) feature will do what you're asking; you can create an "external tool" named `kubectl-apply` with any of the variables they support, and then invoke it via any number of built-in mechanisms

[image: the IntelliJ External Tools configuration dialog]

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Kubernetes extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools) for VS Code and new k8s related commands will appear in Command Pallete.

For example `Kubernetes: Apply` - executes `kubectl apply` for currently active file. You can also bind hotkeys to these commands.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alik. Where do I see the output of Kubernetes: Apply? I have a very large yaml file (istio-demo.yaml) which can take a long time. It is not clear if VS Code is still applying it or is finished.

Comment: @user674669 notification message will appear in the right bottom of vscode window after the command is completed. You can try experimenting with small yaml files to see how it works.